# Vuex + firebase database actions

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuex

I'm using firebase in my app with Vuex.  I have this action in vuex

```
async deleteTodo({ commit }, id) {
        await fbs.database().ref(`/todolist/${store.state.auth.userId}/${id}`)
            .remove()
            .then(() => {
                // fix this
                console.log('Todo deleted', commit);
            })
    }
```

How can I skip `{commit}`in params, if I don't need to commit something. I have error like 'commit assigned but never used'

Comment: Dont destructure the object, use just a placeholder underscore: deleteTodo(_, id)

Answer (score 2):

`deleteTodo({ commit }, id)` destructures the first parameter. What your action actually receives there is a `context` object that has a couple of members. `commit` is one of those. By destructuring it like this, you implicitly assign it to a local constant, and then don't use it. Linters don't like that. If you were to replace it with `deleteTodo(context, id)` there's a good chance your linter will accept it. If it doesn't, you can also use `deleteTodo(_, id)`, though I'd go with the former. (But there's something else you do want to destructure here... read below.)

Although if you're not committing anything as part of these actions, why is this in Vuex? You could simply put it in any stand-alone function. Vuex is specifically for managing state.

Ah, but you do use state! You use `store.state.auth.userId`, but you access it from a constant local to your file, presumably the one uses to create the store, instead of the actual state of the store. This will probably work fine in most cases, but it's not the preferred way to do it.

You know where you can also find the state? On that same context object! So best would be to rewrite it like this:

```
async deleteTodo({ state }, id) {
    await fbs.database().ref(`/todolist/${state.auth.userId}/${id}`)
        .remove()
        .then(() => {
            // fix this
            console.log('Todo deleted');
        });
}
```

That's the best way to do it.